# EF 5 Find profiler

Tags: c#, sql, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5

I use EF 5 for my project and im profilin it with EntityProfiler and i see that sql that is generated whene i use Find for the query is:

```
SELECT TOP (2) [Extent1].[ID]                  AS [ID],
               [Extent1].[TargetID]            AS [TargetID],
               [Extent1].[BranchID]            AS [BranchID],
               [Extent1].[ApplicationStatus]   AS [ApplicationStatus],
               [Extent1].[UserID]              AS [UserID],
               [Extent1].[AssignedOfficer]     AS [AssignedOfficer],
               [Extent1].[AssignedOfficerCRM]  AS [AssignedOfficerCRM],
               [Extent1].[RegistrationDate]    AS [RegistrationDate],
               [Extent1].[DecisionReasons]     AS [DecisionReasons],
               [Extent1].[DecisionExceptionID] AS [DecisionExceptionID],
               [Extent1].[RiskComment]         AS [RiskComment],
               [Extent1].[CESInformed]         AS [CESInformed],
               [Extent1].[IsCommited]          AS [IsCommited]
FROM   [dbo].[Applications] AS [Extent1]
WHERE  [Extent1].[ID] = '900100' /* @p0 */
```

Code that is called is:

```
 public T GetByID(object primaryKey)
        {
            return DB.Set<T>().Find(primaryKey);
        }
```

so my questin is why in sql that is generated is Select Top (2)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It executes `Select Top (2)` cause the DBSet uses internally `SingleOrDefault()` (see [here](http://entityframework.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/aebf648fa9de#src/EntityFramework/Internal/Linq/InternalSet%60.cs) method `FindInStore`) for the `Find` method to execute the query.

This ensures, that if 2 results are returned, an exception is thrown, cause SingleOrDefault defines that it expects exactly one result or nothing.

`Select Top (1)` is generated as Sql wenn you use FirstOrDefault().